# Importing a pdf image in R markdown

Tags: r, import, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to import a pdf file into R Markdown.

The pdf file name is `"question7.pdf"`.

I am trying to import the image using `knitr::include_graphics()` but I have no idea on how to use the code properly.

Could someone help me?

Tks !

Answer (score -1):

Just running

```r
knitr::include_graphics("question7.pdf")
```

inside an R code chunk in your RMarkdown file should work. Assuming that `question7.pdf` is in the same folder as your Rmd file.